# when use "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file_path" from root not working

Tags: gsettings

I when use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file_path` from root not working but run from Anotheruser it`s work.

Even when I put it inside crontab -u Anotheruser -e. But not working

My os : ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I tried all the way but it did not.

Example :

```
su - USER -c "command" 
# or ways sudo and su
crontab -u USER -e
DISPLAY=:1 ...
DISPLAY=:0 ...
DISPLAY=:0.0 ...
dbus-launch ...
PID=$(pgrep gnome-session)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= ...
```

please Help me! thanks

Comment: What are you hoping to gain from running that command as root?

Comment: No
.this command just run as otheruser.

Comment: Nobody knows???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution** :

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(pgrep -a dbus-daemon -U USERNAME | grep -o 'unix:abstract.*$')
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri FILE_ADDRESS
```

AND into crontab :

```
@reboot su USERNAME -c 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(pgrep -a dbus-daemon -U USERNAME | grep -o "unix:abstract.*$");export DISPLAY=:0;gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri FILE_ADDRESS'
```

just replace `USERNAME` by your user AND replace `FILE_ADDRESS` by your picture Address